# Limit of the sequence $\sqrt[n]{|\cos(n)|}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I read in a french book (corrected annals of centrale école) that

it's **not hard** to prove that

$\lim\limits \sqrt[n]{|\cos(n)|} = 1$

I wonder how to prove this.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Here is the same question about $\sqrt[n]{|\sin(n)|}$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251755/is-this-sequence-convergent. I strongly assume that the same technique can be applied.

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking at the "local minimums" at $n=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$

Comment: What might be difficult here is the claim that it is **not hard** to prove.  Given the context of where that claim was made might shed light on what thinking lies behind it.  Was this a high school text or a research level publication?